# Python get observation with nearest value

Tags: python

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
    Segment  Distance   ID
    3        0.348      1203
    8        0.439      1204
    4        0.458      1205
    8        0.284      1207
    3        0.359      1208
    8        0.563      1209
    4        0.388      1210
```

I want to be able to enter `id = '1203'`in python
and get 3 of the nearest observations according to the distance.

So when I enter `id = '1203'`, this is my desired output

```
    Segment  Distance   ID
    3        0.359      1208
    4        0.388      1210
    8        0.284      1207
```

I only want my output to be based on the distance variable, not segment, but I want the respective segment number to show up in my output.

I know it's a simple problem, but I am fairly new to python, so I am a little confused on how to approach this. Can someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible multiple IDs (including '1203') have the same distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the distance from ID '1203' then subtract its distance to the whole dataframe and sort values. Drop the first row (ID '1203') and keep the next three ones:

```
dist = df.loc[df['ID'] == '1203', 'Distance'][0]
out = df.loc[df['Distance'].sub(dist).abs().sort_values().tail(-1).head(3).index]
print(out)

# Output:
   Segment  Distance    ID
4        3     0.359  1208
6        4     0.388  1210
3        8     0.284  1207
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a good approach is to sort by 'Distance' col.
then get the next three rows with **loc** function

```
df.sort_values(by=['Distance'])

df.loc[:'1203'].head(3)
```